# OAuth GitHub Authentication from single page React app

Tags: reactjs, github-api

I'm trying to integrate my single page React app with GitHub.

I successfully run first stage of authentication, i.e. receiving redirect with `code` from https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize

The problem is the second part, i.e. POST to https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token

I can't do POST or GET from my web page itself via JavaScript or JQuery. Using `$.ajax` or `$.post` all end up with error `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

The app was created with `create-react-app` and run with `npm start`.

How can I avoid `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error in my scenario? Is there a way to get GitHub token for GitHub API in some other way?

I've tried to do POST with , and it does not complain on `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. In fact after `.submit()` I receive expected response (as per https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/#web-application-flow) but it comes as a file, which Chrome immediately downloads.

Comment: you should do this from your server

Comment: I'm using single page React app so that my entire app functions without any "smart" server infrastructure and can run entirely in a browser. Is it possible to use GitHub API entirely from browser?

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/apollographql/GitHunt-React , 
is this example what you want to achive?

Comment: @hod caspi If I do POST via server, will it require any cookies? Do initial GET to GitHub returns any authentication related cookies?